# Crontab + Ruby on Rails: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory

Tags: cron, path, ruby

I have a ruby on rails app and I need to schedule a crontab for a rake task.

```
*/5 * * * * RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/rake -f /usr/local/www/mysite-web-production/current/Rakefile my_site:export_products >> /var/log/export_feed.log 3>&1
```

However, it's not working (it works when I do it manually, but not as a crontab) and it's showing me `/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory`. 
I'm not using RVM. I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3 on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Wherever ruby is, it's not in the `$PATH` of `cron`. Find the actual location of `ruby` by running `type -a`. Then add it's path to the `$PATH` environment variable in your crontab.

Example, if you find `type -a` shows that the path to `ruby` is `/usr/local/bin/ruby` (and judging by your path to `rake` it likely is), your crontab should look like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
*/5 * * * * RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/bin/rake -f /usr/local/www/mysite-web-production/current/Rakefile my_site:export_products >> /var/log/export_feed.log 3>&1
```

Or possibly:

```
*/5 * * * * RAILS_ENV=production PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin/rake -f /usr/local/www/mysite-web-production/current/Rakefile my_site:export_products >> /var/log/export_feed.log 3>&1
```

Either should work.

Comment: Thanks! let me try it out. `type -a` didn't return anything though.